# Getting the correct ID to delete in site with multiple posts

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I just ran into an issue I just can't get my head around.

I have a site with all the applications a user has made, looking like this:
[image: dashboard]

I have a button to delete/cancel on each post this exact post (`Bewerbung zurückziehen`).

When pressing that button, a modal opens with some text. When he presses the delete button in the modal the application is canceled if the user is sure to delete it.

However, it is always the first on the page that gets deleted, not the one on which the button was pressed.

I have to somehow get the application's ID on which the button was pressed, but I have zero clue on how to do it.

Here is the blade code:

```html
<div class="flex-grow">
    @foreach($bewerbungen as $bewerbung)
        @foreach($stellenanzeigen_names as $stellenanzeigen_name)
            @if($bewerbung->Stellenanzeigen_ID === $stellenanzeigen_name->Stellenanzeigen_ID)
                <div class="p-10 grid-cols-3 grid-rows-3 gap-4 shadow-2xl mb-10 grey_bg border-solid border-2 border-black rounded-lg">
                    <!--Card 1-->
                    <div>
                        {{ $stellenanzeigen_name->Titel }}
                        <hr class="border-black">
                    </div>
                    <div class="pt-4 pl-8 font-medium text-xl font-bold font-serif">
                        ID der Bewerbung: {{ $bewerbung->Bewerbung_ID }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="pt-4 pl-8 pb-3 font-medium text-xl font-bold font-serif">
                        ID der Stellenanzeige: {{ $bewerbung->Stellenanzeigen_ID }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex justify-end">
                        <button type="submit"
                                name="open_btn"
                                class="open-btn mr-8 text-black px-4 py-3 rounded text-base font-medium button_bg float-right shadow transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100"
                        >
                            Bewerbung zurückziehen
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cancel_appl_modal"
                         class="modal fixed ml-96 top-20 mx-auto p-5 border w-96 shadow-lg rounded-md post_bg hidden text-white">
                        <div class="mt-3 text-center text-2xl">
                            Bewerbung zurückziehen
                        </div>

                        <div class="items-center px-4 py-3">
                            <label for="neue_telefonnummer" class="sr-only">Neue Telefonnummer</label>

                            <form method="post"
                                  action="{{ route('delete', $bewerbung->Bewerbung_ID) }}">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="text-lg mb-4">
                                    Wenn Sie die Bewerbung zurückziehen haben Sie keinen Zugriff mehr
                                    auf alle Daten.
                                    Die Daten werden jedoch noch im System archiviert.
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit"
                                        id="ok_btn"
                                        class="mb-4 pb-3 w-full text-black px-4 py-3 rounded text-base font-medium bg-teal float-right shadow transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100 shadow-2xl border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg"
                                >
                                    Bewerbung zurückziehen
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="items-center px-4 py-3">
                            <button id="back_btn"
                                    class="mb-4 pb-3 w-full text-black px-4 py-3 rounded text-base font-medium bg-teal float-right shadow transition duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100 shadow-2xl border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg"
                            >
                                zurück
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endif
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</div>
```

This is the JS code for the modal:

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.open-btn');

var delete_appl_modal = document.getElementById("cancel_appl_modal");

buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        // this is where you would open the modal
        delete_appl_modal.style.display = 'block';
        console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
    })
});

var submit_btn = document.getElementById("ok_btn");

var back_btn = document.getElementById("back_btn");

open.onclick = function () {
    delete_appl_modal.style.display = "block";
}

back_btn.onclick = function () {
    delete_appl_modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        delete_appl_modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your modal created inside a `foreach`, and there's no unique `id` of modal, your first created modal will always used. My suggestion, 1) Use your Bewerbungen id for additional modal id, so every modal will have different id. 2), Take your modal out of `foreach`, and use javascript for setting the id on which Bewerbungen you want to delete. And I prefer to use the second one, since if you created so many Modal, it's waste of resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your form :

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('delete', $bewerbung->Bewerbung_ID)}}">
```

but it's in a loop, so presumably you are creating lots of them, each with the same button with the same ID :

```
<button type="submit" id="ok_btn"  ... >
```

Since ID has to be unique, when your javascript fires, it looks for the element with ID "ok_btn" to submit the relevant form. Since there are lots (again, ID should be unique) then it just submits the first one it comes to. So it will always just delete the first one on the page.

My suggestion would be :

1. Don't put the form or the modal in the loop.
2. Put the modal at the end, with the form inside it, and within the form have a hidden field (called, say, "delete_id".
3. Use javascript to populate the "delete_id" with the relevant ID of the thing to be deleted when the user clicks to bring up the modal.
4. Use the confirmation button to submit the form, as you do at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @Giles Bennett for taking time to answer! It is a great way of answering as well, hint in the right direction but not the solution. I will get to work and try to implement your tipps! Maybe I get back to you, but I hope I don't :D

Comment: No problem. I've got some code somewhere (I come across this issue a lot) if you need it, but quick hint is to use data-attributes in the buttons that trigger the modal to store the ID of the thing you want to delete (not sure what it is, my German's not great!) and then read that data-attribute  with your javascript to populate the hidden input in the form.

Comment: I just had a meeting so I couldn’t try it, but I will soon. The posts are Job applications from the user. He whole project is a job application Portal :) I am veeeeery inexperienced with JavaScript but I hope you don’t need to send me the code :D

Comment: Hey @Giles Bennett :) I don't really understand your third point, how can I get the exact relevant id? So how can I know if the user clicked on the first, third or whatever post/button ? :/

Comment: I tried it this way now: I set the id of the button to `$bewerbung->Bewerbung_ID` - I console.log it when a button is pressed and I get the correct Bewerbung_ID - so it pretty much works to set the button ID according to which button is pressed. Now my idea was to get the button id and pass it with the route like so `{{ route('delete', $button_id) }} - but that doesn't work :/

Comment: i have a solution!! :D it is a bit of a dirty work around but it works :D

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with a small workaround!

I moved the modal out of the loops, as suggested in the comments / answers, and then I added two hidden input fields:

```
<form method="post"
                                  action="{{ route('delete', $bewerbung->Bewerbung_ID) }}">
                                @csrf
                                <div class="text-lg mb-4">
                                    Wenn Sie die Bewerbung zurückziehen haben Sie keinen Zugriff mehr
                                    auf alle Daten.
                                    Die Daten werden jedoch noch im System archiviert.
                                </div>
                                <input type="hidden" id="email" name="email" value="{{ $bewerbung->bewerber_email }}">
                                <input type="hidden" id="delete_id" name="delete_id" value="">
                                <button type="submit" id="ok_btn" class="mb-4 pb-3 w-full text-black px-4 py-3 rounded text-base font-medium
                                                bg-teal float-right shadow transition
                                                duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100
                                                shadow-2xl border-2 w-full p-4 rounded-lg">
                                    Bewerbung zurückziehen
                                </button>
                            </form>
```

So with the first field the email of the user is passed to the controller and with the second one I assign the value with this javascript code:

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
        {
            document.getElementById("delete_id").value = clicked_id;
        }
```

The button that open the modal now looks like this:

```
<button type="submit" name="open_btn" class="open-btn mr-8 text-black px-4 py-3 rounded text-base font-medium
                                                    button_bg float-right shadow transition
                                duration-500 ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:scale-100" id="{{$bewerbung->Bewerbung_ID}}" onclick="reply_click(this.id)">Bewerbung
                                    zurückziehen
                                </button>
```

Thanks to all in the comments, your hints led me to the right direction :)